# Python gdal stopped working when using ogr Within, Contains or other

Tags: python, windows, gdal, shapely, ogr

**Update:** By further ivestigation I found out it must be caused by somehow corrupted geometry. But even if I run:

```
if drillhole[1].IsValid():
```

It is causing the crash. So not sure how to check it.

I am trying to test if lines are within polygons. Using shapely it works for me very well except of speed - I have ten thousands of lines and the same for polygons. I just wanted to test if ogr can do this faster but no luck to make it work.

```
import ogr
#Load cells as polygons with slight buffer
data_source = ogr.Open(file_path_cells)
source_layer = data_source.GetLayer()
source_layer.ResetReading()
cells = []
for source_feature in source_layer:
  feature_id = source_feature.GetFieldAsInteger(0)
  feature_geometry = source_feature.geometry()
  feature_geometry = feature_geometry.Buffer(0.1, quadsecs = 3)
  cells.append((feature_id,feature_geometry))

#Load drillholes as lines wihtin cells
data_source = ogr.Open(file_path_drillholes)
source_layer = data_source.GetLayer()
source_layer.ResetReading()
drillholes = []
for source_feature in source_layer:
  feature_elev = source_feature.GetFieldAsInteger("elev")
  feature_geometry = source_feature.geometry()
  drillholes.append((feature_elev,feature_geometry))  
for cell in cells:
  for drillhole in drillholes:
    if cell[1].Contains(drillhole[1]):
      print("yes")
    else:
      print("no")
```

Any idea what can be wrong with the line?:

```
if cell[1].Contains(drillhole[1]):
```

On both my Windows 7 machines I allways get python.exe stopped working...
Problem signature:

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5193f3af
  Fault Module Name:    gdal111.dll
  Fault Module Version: 1.11.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   54e65215
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000005e5fb3
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
```

Or is there some other faster way or way how to improve the speed of this using shapely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is most likely a well documented [gotcha](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Pythoncrashesifyouuseanobjectafterdeletinganobjectithasarelationshipwith).

Similar work can be done with Shapely, which doesn't have that gotcha. Also, the query in the for loop can be done faster by using an [Rtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) index, there are a few Q&A's related to shapely + Rtree out there.

Comment: Thank you, I did it with Shapely first as I wrote in my question. I used shapely_geometry = loads(source_feature.geometry().ExportToWkt()) and with Shapely "contains" worked all good. But wanted to try if ogr can do this operations faster. I guess that Rtree is way to go anyway, thanks again.